# CSS property background-image not working, but it does if used in style="background-image: url(...)"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I have a Bootstrap 4 slide show and I need to set the image for each slide by using the following property:

```
    background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/XXX')
```

Here follows my code, then I will explain what's strange:

```
<div id="home-showcase-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item slide-show-image-1 active"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item slide-show-image-2"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item slide-show-image-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And those are the css properties:

```
.slide-show-image-1 {
    background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/XXX')
}
```

and so on for all 3 images.

The above code doesn't work. When I inspect with the chrome web dev tools, I see that the property background-image has a line through.

BUT! If I use the *exact same property* and url in the *style* attribute, it works!

```
<div id="home-showcase-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/XXX')"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/XXX')"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/XXX')"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How is this possible? I'm sure the URL is correct (if I open it in the browser I see the image) and I'm copying and pasting the whole property so there can be no typos.

Comment: Use your Browser inspector to show you exactly what's going on. Possibly the Network tab.

Comment: _“When I inspect with the chrome web dev tools, I see that the property background-image has a line through.”_ - then you probably have a rule in your stylesheet(s) somewhere, with a higher _specificity_, that overwrites the background-image, or background completely.

Comment: Hmm good point, didn't think of it. Does the style attribute have a higher priority than CSS rule? Both applied to the same HTML element of course

Comment: Try `background` property  instead of `background-image`

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Turned out two CSS rules were in conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Thanks CBroe!

Turned out that the following property that I added to *.carousel-inner* was overwriting my CSS rules:

```
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
```

So I added it individually to each image rather then globally to the carousel, not sure if there is a more clean way rather than pasting and copying it 3 times, but still it works